# How to sumproduct of numbers before string if cell contains specific text

Tags: excel

I have cells that contain text like the following:

> 10 - (1/2/20) *C <-- Cell E2

> 10 - (1/3/20)    <-- Cell E3

I am trying to add the numbers before the hyphen if it contains an asterisk.

Using the following formula I get the correct result of "10"

```
=LEFT(E2,FIND("*",E2,1)-13)
```

(surprisingly I can use " * " instead of " ~* " like I thought I would have to?)

Attempting to put it into an array to calculate multiple scenarios I get a #VALUE!

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT(E2:INDEX(E:E,MATCH("zzz",E:E)),FIND("*",E2:INDEX(E:E,MATCH("zzz",E:E)),1)-13)))
```

I assume this is because not all my cells will contain the "*", I am just fumbled on getting things to coordinate correctly.

**Example:**

[image]

Comment: With `FIND`, wild card characters are not allowed, so `*` is interpreted as such and not as a wild card.  An example of what you are trying to do would be more useful than the vague term of "multiple scenarios" causing an error. eg: Examples of input and desired output

Comment: That makes sense about `FIND I did not know that. Updated post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return `30` from your data set, try:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("*",myRange)),--LEFT(myRange,(FIND("-",myRange)-1)),0))
```

*In some earlier versions of Excel, you may need to "confirm" this **array-formula** by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>.  If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula as observed in the formula bar*

[image]

**Algorithm**

- If there is a **`*`**, look for the hyphen and return the value preceding
- If there is no asterisk, return a zero.
- `SUM` the resultant array.

  - *In earlier versions of Excel, using `SUMPRODUCT` instead of `SUM` may allow the formula to be normally entered.  In recent version of Excel, either may be usable with normal entry of the formula.*